# Why am I not able to install PHP on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I have been trying to install laravel for 3 days on ubuntu 16.04. I am following the top search links of laravel installation process. But I failed to execute each and every process I had tried. Now I am facing a different issue on installing PHP on my ubuntu. I had installed maria db once, but did not succeed. 
But it might have broken something that resulted in me not being able to install PHP. The issue I am facing:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php is already the newest version (1:7.2+62+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+3).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `php -v` it gives me this error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718//usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718//usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 07:16:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I am totally new on ubuntu and laravel. And if anyone guide me how to install laravel on ubuntu 16.04 I will be very grateful. 
Thank You.

Comment: It seems like you've tried to enable the mcrypt extension. That's an old and insecure extension that has been removed in PHP 7.2. Try running `sudo phpdismod mcrypt` and see if that works.

Comment: Now , how can I revert this process and install PHP.

Comment: PHP is already installed with latest version on your machine

Comment: OK.. :) but how do I remove that warning msg..??

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I am sorry I did not see your edited code. After applying this code , having `WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available` this msg.

Answer (score 2):

- Install git  `apt-get install git-core`
- `git clone https://github.com/thamaraiselvam/LEMP-Stack-Installer.git`
- `cd quick-lemp-install` or cd LEMP-Stack-Installer
- `chmod +x lemp.sh` this command makes bash script executable
- `./lemp.sh`
  That's it :)

> PHP version - v7.0
>
> Mysql version - Latest Stable
>
> Note: Default mysql password is root. you can change it before running
>   in the following lines before running the script
>
> sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server
>   mysql-server/root_password password YOUR_PASSWORD'
>
> sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server
>   mysql-server/root_password_again password YOUR_PASSWORD'

Now Install Laravel

- Go to `cd /var/www/html/`
- `sudo apt-get install php-common php-mbstring php-xml php-zip`
- `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I execute `sudo apt-get install git-core` it gives me same error `mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed` and I stuck again. :(

Comment: and try to install git clone lempstack set up is everyting like php mysql

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge 'php*'`
`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`
`sudo apt-get purge mysql*`

Comment: After executing your last updated code, there are so many "selecting mysql- servers, utilities.. ", and lastly `Unable to locate package apt-get`, ` Unable to locate package remove`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt

Comment: ok its no problem now try to  install `apt-get install git-core` i hope its working now

Comment: M I need to get root permission to install it. It is asking root permission.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install git-core`

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute the following commands to solve your problem:

- Get the list of MySQL packages installed on the system by executing
  the command `sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql`
- Remove the the packages shown above by executing the command `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove <packages from the step 1>`
- Delete `/var/lib/mysql`
- Try to install `mysql` again. It should solve your problem

Comment: I deleted the folder, execute `sudo apt-get purge 'php*' sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql* sudo apt-get purge mysql*` , but still having that msg `mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed`.. :(